# How to go from x++ to x-- in interval when reaching a specific number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a small javascript program.

The program runs when the windows loads. I set an interval to make the function starts. So I would like to know how can I change from increment to decrement from x++ to i-- when a certain number has been reached in a for loop which goes through each element of an array defined in the beginning of the script ? 
here is my script :

```js
// we create the patterns array
var pattern = [
  [1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 1]
];

var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

// here we assign the width of the cell divs and space margin between them
var WIDTH = 30;
var SPACE = 10;

// here we get the number of rows in an array
var ROWS = pattern.length;

// here we get the number of columns in an array
var COLUMNS = pattern[0].length;

var previousColorNum = 0;

setInterval(render, 2000);

function render() {
  for (var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) {
      // here we create a div element
      var cell = document.createElement("div");

      // here we set the attribute class with the name cell
      cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

      // here we append this new div to stage div
      stage.appendChild(cell);

      // now we check if the element of the array is 1 we give it a background of black
      // if the element is 0 it is white
      if (pattern[row][column] === 1) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      } else if (pattern[row][column] === 2) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else if (pattern[row][column] === 3) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
      previousColorNum = pattern[row][column];
      //pattern[row][column] += 1;

      if (previousColorNum === 3) {
        pattern[row][column] -= 1;
      } else if (previousColorNum === 0) {
        pattern[row][column] += 1;
      }



      // now we make the arrangement of margins for each div cell
      // it is a mathematical formula
      cell.style.top = row * (WIDTH + SPACE) + "px";
      cell.style.left = column * (WIDTH + SPACE) + "px";


      console.log("previous " + previousColorNum);
      console.log("current " + pattern[row][column]);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
.stage {
  position: relative;
}

.cell {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}


/* smaller console */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 2.5em !important; }
```

```html
<div id="stage"></div>
```

Comment: What is X in this code?

Comment: by x i was just giving a general variable

Comment: So what are you trying to do that is not working in this code?

Comment: i am trying to let the increment becomes decrement when a certain number 3 is reached so i want the count to go down instead of up and when it reaches the 0 i want it to go up again and so on

Comment: For loop is not the way to go for your specific situation. I would suggest while loop which loops until X is false. So, you can independently keep a track of a number. Going positive or negative can be determined by some other boolean

Comment: can you please give a code example of that ?